# Access VBA not changing Word color

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using Access to change value in a Word document and I want to change the font color to red for numbers less than zero.  Here's my calling code:

```
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oWord.Visible = True
oWord.Activate
Set doc = oWord.Documents.Open(fpath & "AF Final Costs Notification template.docx", True)
Set oSelection = oWord.Documents(1).Content
oSelection.Select
Set sel = oWord.Selection

Source_Text = "[EstProjCost_AF]"
Replacement_Text = Format(Me.EstProjCost_IF, "currency")
Call Replace_Text(sel, Source_Text, Replacement_Text)
```

and here's my subroutine:

```
Private Sub Replace_Text(sel, Source_Text, Replacement_Text)

Replacement_Text = Nz(Replacement_Text, "--NULL--")
With sel
    .Find.ClearFormatting
    .Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With .Find
        .Text = Source_Text
        .Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorBlack
        If IsNumeric(Replacement_Text) Then
            If Replacement_Text < 0 Then
                .Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorRed
            End If
        End If
        .Replacement.Text = Replacement_Text
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = 1 'wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        sel.Find.Execute Replace:=2  'wdReplaceAll
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

ETA:  here's the Word macro which works as expected:
    Sub change_font()
    Dim Replacement_Text As String

```
'
' change_font Macro
'
'
    Replacement_Text = "def"
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    If IsNumeric(Replacement_Text) Then
        If CInt(Replacement_Text) < 0 Then
            Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorRed
        End If
    End If
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "abc"
        .Replacement.Text = Replacement_Text
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: What problems are you seeing with the current code? Welcome to Stackoverflow

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, be more specific about your problem. Have you activated references to Word Library in your VBA module? Also, another option could be using `.Replacement.Font.Color = vbRed` instead of `.Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorRed`

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

The text is being replaced, but always in black, never in red. 

The macro works just fine in Word VBA (see added macro).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a work-around.  Since all the text I want to change has a pattern of "(-9999.99)", I add this code after the last replace:

```
With sel
    .Find.ClearFormatting
    .Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Find.Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorRed
    With .Find
        .Text = "\(-*\)"
        .Replacement.Text = "^&"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

I'd still like to know why the original code didn't work, but maybe there's a better forum to ask that on...